# I/O Operation Error on a closed file

Tags: python

Can anyone tell me whats wrong with this code.

```
import csv 
import glob

with open("1.csv") as sample:
     reader = csv.reader(sample)
     header = 'Name', 'ID', 'Marks'

with open("out1.csv", "wb") as out1:
     writer = csv.writer(out1)
     writer.writerow(header)


for path in glob.glob("out.csv"):
     if path == "out1.csv": continue
     with open(path) as fh:
           reader = csv.reader(fh)
           for row in reader:
               if row[0] == 'Name' and row[1] == 'ID':
                    writer.writerow(row)
```

Error is I/O operation on closed file
writer.writerow(row)
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file

Comment: can you please put the error message ?

Comment: From `writer.writerow(row)`? You opened the file with the context manager `with` meaning that as soon as you exit that indented block, the file is automatically closed.

Comment: Yes, you've closed the file-handler that you passed to `writer`. The whole point of a `with` block is to *guarantee* that the file will be closed once you exit the block...

Comment: Side note: what are the `sample` and `reader` assignments from the first block used for? They look pretty reducdant to me (as you even re-assign `reader` later on).

Answer (score -1):

You should indent everything:

```
with open("1.csv") as sample:
    ....
    with open("out1.csv", "wb") as out1:
        ....
        for path in glob.glob("out.csv"):
            ....
```